# App.Config C# Fuel SDK Initialisation

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, c#

I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what. I'm just trying to initialise the FuelSDK. I installed the package through NuGet, and I'm just doing some super basic code, but it fails on initialisation.

```c#
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var client = new ETClient();
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException has been thrown
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

My App config looks like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="fuelSDK" type="FuelSDK.FuelSDKConfigurationSection, FuelSDK" />
  </configSections>
  <fuelSDK 
    appSignature="blah"
    clientId="blah" 
    clientSecret="blah" 
    authEndPoint="https://blah.auth.marketingcloudapis.com" 
    soapEndPoint="https://blah.soap.marketingcloudapis.com" 
    restEndPoint="https://blah.rest.marketingcloudapis.com" />
</configuration>
```

---

**EDIT** Thanks to Jackson's helpful post, the original issue was due to being on a Mac. I added the following NuGet packages, and managed to get past that error:

- `System.ServiceModel.Primitives`
- `System.ServiceModel.Http`
- `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`

However, now I get the following problem:

> System.Exception has been thrown clientId or clientSecret is null: Must be provided in config file or passed when instantiating ETClient.

[image: Endpoint settings]

There's clearly something I'm missing at the elementary level, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the NuGet package and not FuelSDK: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/575

Try using a stable version: [4.4.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Primitives/4.4.1.)

Comment: Hey thanks Jackson you were correct! Maybe it's because I'm on a Mac. I ended up adding:
System.ServiceModel.Primitives
System.ServiceModel.Http
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

However, now I get the following problem:
System.Exception has been thrown clientId or clientSecret is null: Must be provided in config file or passed when instantiating ETClient

Comment: Are you using the correct client id and client secret? If you log into the relevant Business Unit, Click Administration from the drop down under your user name.
 Account > Installed Packages

Comment: I don't think it is... I've uploaded the settings from the installed packages...